# How do I deploy my NextJs app and API made with ExpressJS all together in same domain? like myapp.com api.myapp.com

Tags: api, express, next.js, dns, hosting

So I made an app with Nextjs ( one git repo) and the backend api with Express JS (another git repo)

How can I deploy them together as like myapp.com / api.myapp.com  or  myapp.com/api

also what are the options for free/cheap hostings?

thanks

I have tried with render.com and vercel using a domain from Cloudflare and connecting DNS and couldnt get what i was looking for

Comment: Vercel meets your listed requirements - free, can host your Next and Express sites, can use your own domain/subdomain, and sites/api can be hosted from one or multiple repos.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use two different hostnames (myapp.com and api.myapp.com), then you can keep your code as is and have two deployments, one for each hostname.  If you want to have the two codebases work off the same hostname (ie myapp.com/api), then it's best to combine the two codebases into one repo and have the express site server the nextjs pages as static files.

Here is how to configure express to serve static pages https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

If you really want to use two hostnames and have a single code base, there are ways of having that done as well.  You would have the code in express check the hostname and then run the appropriate code.